# i have used Bottom navigaion with navigation drawer both with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I an Working On a project which uses navigation drawer with bottom navigation view
my navigation drawer is working fine but when i click any options from bottom navigation it gets selected but not shows anything in framelayout Here Is My XML File Please Help Me..
none of fragment of bottom navigation drawer are showing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Home_Activity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/yellow"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/blue"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:itemHorizontalPadding="40dp"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#fecd99"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_sort_24px" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And Here Is My Java File

```
package com.anshdev.anshapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.anshdev.anshapp.Navigation_drawer.about_us_fragment;
import com.anshdev.anshapp.Navigation_drawer.categories_fragment;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class Home_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        /* <-------------------------Hooks--------------------->*/
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        /*<-------------------Tool Bar-------------->*/
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        /*<-------------------NAVIGATION DRAWER MENU-------------->*/
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home_nav);
//--------------------BOTTOM NAVIGATION-----------------------
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(selectedListener);
        //default-selected-bottom-nav
        Home home = new Home();
        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft1.replace(R.id.framelayout, home, null);
        ft1.commit();

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home_nav:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.categories_nav:
                fragment = new categories_fragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;

            case R.id.about_us_nav:
                fragment = new about_us_fragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener selectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home_bottom_nav:
                            Home home = new Home();
                            FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft1.replace(R.id.framelayout, home, null);
                            ft1.commit();
                            return true;

                        case R.id.menu_bottom_nav:
                            Menu menu = new Menu();
                            FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft2.replace(R.id.framelayout, menu, null);
                            ft2.commit();
                            return true;

                        case R.id.fav_nav_bottom:
                            Favourites Fav = new Favourites();
                            FragmentTransaction ft3 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft3.replace(R.id.framelayout, Fav, null);
                            ft3.commit();
                            return true;

                        case R.id.user_bottom_profile:
                            User_Profile Userprofile = new User_Profile();
                            FragmentTransaction ft4 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft4.replace(R.id.framelayout, Userprofile, null);
                            ft4.commit();
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

}
```

Please Help Me...

Comment: is the method onNavigationItemSelected called?

Comment: You have two `FrameLayout`s for `Fragment` containers, and the one used by `BottomNavigationView`'s transactions is underneath the one used by the `NavigationView`. You want only one container for all of your `Fragment`s, and only one main content in the `DrawerLayout`. Move the `<MaterialToolbar>` into the first `<LinearLayout>`, get rid of the second `<LinearLayout>` and `<FrameLayout>` altogether, and then use that one remaining `<FrameLayout>`'s ID for all of the `replace()` calls.